# Interview - Positioning and resetting a ball in the center

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was faced with this question in one of my interviews and was completely stumped. The only solution I could think of was storing the `currentAngle` in a `NSArray` to calculate the next angle.

**Question:**
Move a 35px ball across the screen utilizing the iPhone's compass. Once the ball is in the center of the screen, let the user tap it to 'reset' the position. Once reset, the ball will go back to the `Min` position. Remember that the compass may start somewhere between 0-359, the task is to find the nearest capture angle and focus on that angle until the ball is aligned. Once the ball is aligned & reset, the iPhone will move to the next angle and so forth until the ball has been reset `18` times. `18 resets` * `20 degree angles` = `360`.

**Assigned Variables:**

```
int currentAngle = (Ranging between 0-359) (Constant updates as the user twirls around)

int captureAngle = 20

int centerX = view.center.x (160) - 35 (size of ball)

int ballSize = 35 (ball.width/2)
```

The paper looked something like this:

[image]

**Function so far:**

```
-(void)testMotion{
    motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;

    if (([CMMotionManager availableAttitudeReferenceFrames] & CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical) != 0) {
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical
                                                           toQueue:motionQueue
                                                       withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
         {
             if (!error) {
                 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                     CMAttitude *attitude = motion.attitude;
                     CMRotationMatrix rm = attitude.rotationMatrix;

                     // Get the heading.
                     double heading = M_PI + atan2(rm.m22, rm.m12);
                     heading = heading*180/M_PI;

                     int currentAngle = (int)heading;
                     NSLog(@"Current Angle: %d",currentAngle);

                     int captureAngle = 20; // 20 Degress Capture Angle

                 }];
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give more details - what is captureAngle? , and by "until the ball is aligned" - meaning until the ball is at the center of the screen?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry for the confusion. `captureAngle` is the "target" angle. In other words, the angle of where the ball will be in the center.. I know it's confusing, but just imagine a ball starting on the `Min` position, and as you rotate your phone, the `currentAngle` variable updates, and if the `currentAngle` is +20, the ball will be in the middle of the screen. Once the user taps the ball, the phone will move on to the second angle in the segment (in other words, the `currentAngle` == 20 + 20).

Comment: In other words, let's play with the thought and imagine that `currentAngle` == 0. As you rotate your phone, `currentAngle` will either update to (360 -> rotating right), or 0+ (rotating left). So if I were to do, `if(currentAngle==captureAngle)`, it would match when the  `currentAngle==20`. However, the problem is that `currentAngle` can start somewhere between `0-360` and it's not possible to know where it'll start. The objective of the question is to create a function that 'detects' when the `currentAngle` has been updated with +20 and then update that to the frame of `centerX`.

Comment: I really hope any of this makes sense.

Comment: yes it does. will think about it

Comment: but the currentAngle keeps changing as the device rotates, so why not just wait for it to be at the angle we want it to be? (while currentAngle! = captureAngle - do nothing...)

Comment: probably I'm missing something

Comment: Good point! But the goal is to find the first angle that is available and focus on that until the ball has been 'tapped'. So if the `currentAngle` == 160, the goal behind the first 'reset' would be to check for `180`.

Comment: Another solution might be to check for if (currentAngle has increased by 20). The problem behind that though is that if the `currentAngle ` is 359, then 379 would never be true.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you, then it's something like this:
calculate the x and y movement from the angle 
(see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

http://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?id=system/2006/1223522781
)

Then move the ball according to those values, and if it moved by an angle of 20 - allow reset it or get out of the loop (for your choice)

```
    while(1) {

    x = r \cos(currentAngle)

    y = r \sin(currentAngle)

    //change the ball position, 
    ball.position.x += x*speed
    ball.position.y += y*speed

    //check if angel is +20 or -20
    if (((currentAngle + 20) % 360) != captureAngle && (abs(currentAngle - 20) % 360) != captureAngle)) {
        allow_reset_ball = true
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! That works for detecting if the ball is in the captureAngle.. But what about moving the ball until it reaches it? I.e. Set the UIFrame of the ball until the ball is in the position.

Comment: it's depend on how complicated the answer supposed to be. it's can be simple as set the ball position to the center of the screen 
ball.position =  view.center.x

Comment: Sure, but what I'm trying to say is, the problem with a while loop is that it pauses action until the condition is true.. So, even if I set the balls position to `Min` position, the balls position will not move parallel to the `currentAngle` until the condition is true.

Comment: That looks great! However, not sure where you get the `r` & `speed` variables from.. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: decide what you want them to be, usually it's doesn't matter at those kind of interview questions, it's just to see that you have the general direction on how to solve those problems.

Comment: (and of course you can ask the interviewer what those values are)

Comment: Sure, that's true.. But because I'm so new to the field of rotations & axes, I'd like to have the complete answer so I can learn and evolve from it :) Really hope you don't mind

Comment: I guess `speed` could be anything, but what about `r`? What functionality does `r` have?

Comment: the radius of the ball. in your case it ball.width / 2

Comment: Got it! Let me write up a quick Obj-C demo and test it out! Thanks a lot

Comment: u r welcome. but again - maybe it's meant to be a question to solve only on paper - because it's depends on the implementation - for example how the interviewer implemented the ball (physic object ? just uiview ?), how he implemented the compass which will get the angle, and a lot of stuff like that

Comment: Yes that is true, but I really can't get this out of my head until I've successfully implemented a test that works :). I've updated my question with a code block that seems to detect that the ball is in the scope instantly as the program starts. Not sure why..

Comment: sry, change  if (((currentAngle + 20) % 360) != captureAngle && (abs(currentAngle - 20) % 360) != captureAngle) {
                         NSLog(@"Ball is within the scope!");
                     }
to 
 if (((currentAngle + 20) % 360) == captureAngle || (abs(currentAngle - 20) % 360) == captureAngle) {
                         NSLog(@"Ball is within the scope!");
                     }

and it will work.

If it helped you, I'll appreciate the  bounty :)

Comment: Hmm.. I did change it to what you suggested, but it still doesn't fire.. Did you try it out?

Comment: what do u mean by doesn't fire ?

Comment: I started the application and the `currentAngle` read 269, as I rotated my phone and it hit 249, the if statement didn't execute.

Comment: oh, at the if part, add 
captureAngle =  (currentAngle + 20) % 360

Comment: so at the first time, you are looking for  rotation of 20 or 340, and then at the second time you will look for 40 or 0, and so on..

Comment: I just tried it, same thing, the if statement never executes.. Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have access to xcode at the moment, I'll check it a bit later. But you can print the logs - what is currentAngle and what is captureAngle before the if condition.

Comment: mainly - check that you are really update currentAngle via the "compass"

Comment: Sure, here's the log: `First started application: Current Angle: 269` & then when I align it to 249, `Current Angle: 249`. But `Ball is within the scope!` never shows up in the console.

Comment: I've updated the question with my current code block.

Comment: but what is captureAngle

Comment: int captureAngle = 20; // 20 Degress Capture Angle

Comment: try rotating it to reach rotation of 0 or of 40

Comment: I just tried that, both 0 and 40 executes successfully.

Comment: yep, because as you wanted at the original question, at first we are looking for rotation of 0 or 40, and after that, we r looking for a rotation of +20 from the one before it.

Comment: Not quite.. The question states `Remember that the compass may start somewhere between 0-359, the task is to find the nearest capture angle and focus on that angle until the ball is aligned.`. What I mean by that is that if the `currentAngle` is 269, then the if statement should execute at 249 -- then 229 -- 209 and so forth.

Comment: But since we don't know what the `currentAngle` is, the if statement must be able to execute at 20-40-60 as-well.

Comment: Actually, it'll look like this: 0->340->320->300.

Comment: then change the if condition to what it was before:
if (((currentAngle + 20) % 360) == captureAngle || ((360 + currentAngle - 20)%360) == captureAngle) {
                         NSLog(@"Ball is within the scope!");
                     }

Comment: and in your function, you may want to change  int captureAngle = 20;  to the angle you want it to be

Comment: Perhaps its not clear enough... Capture angle is only the angle of where the ball should be aligned.. In other words, `if captureAngle = 20` and `currentAngle = 240`, then the IF statement should check for 220. Once reset, the IF statement should check for 200, 180, 160 and so forth.

Comment: You may ask.. Why 20? Well, 20 * 18 resets = 360 degrees.

Comment: that what it does at the moment

Comment: so you forgot to add  **   captureAngle = (currentAngle + 20) % 360 *** to the if part, as I said before.
and I think the answer gave you almost full implementation of the answer you were looking for, so the rest is up to you.

Comment: Like so? `if (((currentAngle + 20) % 360) == captureAngle || ((360 + currentAngle - 20)%360) == captureAngle) {
                         captureAngle = (currentAngle + 20) % 360;
                         NSLog(@"Ball is within the scope!");
                     }`

Comment: Best thing would be if you could try it out for yourself in xCode whenever you have a few minutes on your hands..

Comment: don't sure I get u, but maybe what you want is to add 
 int captureAngle = 20; // 20 Degress Capture Angle
int lastAngle = 0;
and replace the if to:
if ( (currentAngle + 20) %360 == lastAngle || (360 + currentAngle - 20)%360 == lastAngle) { NSLOG("within scope"); lastAngle = currentAngle + 20; }

Comment: That makes `captureAngle` unused and really doesn't change anything. I suggest trying the sample code above out for yourself.

Comment: the sample code by itself won't even enter to the motionManager Handler.

Comment: What do you mean??